# google mobile ads sdk linking issue

Tags: ios, linker, ads

I have an issue integrating Google Mobile Ads SDK.
I am working with Xcode 5.1 and I trying cocoa pods.
What I did is the following:

in my pod file I wrote

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '7.0'
pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK', '~> 7.0'
```

then I run pod install and I got

```
Installing Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK (7.0.0)
```

In my app source code simply I wrote:

```
#import <GoogleMobileAds/GoogleMobileAds.h>
```

and then

```
GADAdSize adMobSize = kGADAdSizeSmartBannerLandscape;
GADBannerView *adMobView = [[GADBannerView alloc]
initWithAdSize:adMobSize];
```

but I got the following linking error:

```
(null): "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GADBannerView", referenced from:

(null): Objc-class-ref in RMAMainViewController.o

(null): "_kGADAdSizeSmartBannerLandscape", referenced from:

(null): -[RMAMainViewController initWithNibName:bundle:] in RMAMainViewController.o

(null): Symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

(null): Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: Are you putting your `adUnitID` and add in as `subview`?

Comment: Yes already put. But the problem was in cocoa pods and Xcode 5. I have switched to Xcode 6 and also I had to put in Other Linker Flags the string -Objc and not -ObjC. Seems strange but it is the only way to let it work for me. Thank you anyway.

Comment: Thats strange because, according to [AdMob release notes](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/rel-notes#ios), in version 7.0.0 you doesn't have o put the `-ObjC` any more

Comment: Okay you are right in fact my actual issue was in project configuration. Once solved that, I could also import this framework without tricky hacks. Thank you anyway.